# Prove a given sequence is a Martingale

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, expectation, martingales, conditional-expectation

Let $C = [0, 1]$. Let $P$ be the uniform probability law on $C$. Let $X : [0, 1] → \mathbb{R}$
be a random variable such that $X(t) = t^2$ for all $t ∈ [0, 1]$. 
For every integer $k > 1$, let $s = 2^{-k}$
, let $$A_k
:= \{[0, s), [s, 2s), [2s, 3s), . . . , [1−2s, 1−s), [1−s, 1)\}$$, and let $$M_k
:= E(X|A_k)$$

Show that the increments $M_2 − M_1$, $M_3 − M_2$, . . . are orthogonal in the following sense.

For any  $i, j ≥ 1$ with $i \neq j$,$$E(M_{i+1} − M_i)(M_{j+1} − M_j ) = 0$$

The statement that  I want to prove looks like the orthogonality of Martingale, so the remaining thing is to show that $M_K$ is a Martingale. However, I really stuck here since I could not even find another sequence of random variables that $M_k$ is adapted to.

Hope you can help me out!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: $M_k$ is adapted to the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing $A_k$. This is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the random variable $\sum_{n=0}^{2^k - 1}n\mathbf{1}([ns, (n + 1)s))$.

Comment: @BenDerrett Thank you for your replying! I will try to look into it. But I did not learn $\sigma$-algebra stuff. Is there a way to see it in another(simpler) way?

Comment: "The statement that  I want to prove looks like the orthogonality of Martingale, so the remaining thing is to show that $M_K$ is a Martingale." No, you are turning things upside down, actually "the remaining thing is to show that" $E(M_{i+1} − M_i)(M_{j+1} − M_j ) = 0$.

Comment: @Did Will you please give me some hint on how to start it?

Comment: OK, assume that $i<j$, can you prove that $E(M_iM_j)=E(M_i^2)$?

Comment: @Did I'm sorry, I think I'm a little dumb when the discrete random variable takes too many values. I cannot prove it.